# A teaser on center of mass of right circular cone?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, geometry

How can a distinction be made between the centre of mass of a right circular cone

1. As a uniform solid ($\frac{h}{4}$ from base, where is $h$ is height)
   and
2. That composed of infinitesimally small thickness of right triangles of the same height and base (same as radius of cone). In which case it apparently appears to be $\frac{h}{3}$ from base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the fact that point 2 is not a valid separation of a cone into sub-parts. It should instead be separated into triangular-based pyramids with small-angled isosceles triangle at the base. The center of mass of *that* thing is at `h/4`.

This is how a small element would look:

[image: conesector]

The vertex of the cone is up at the top `{x,y,z}=={2,0,0}`. The base of this element is a sector of a circle.

Comment: You are right ! Seems to explain. One more aspect needs to be addressed in this context, how come rectangles be able to make up a right circular cylinder ? Though sometimes wrong approximations may result in right answers, is this then the right way to conclude ?

Comment: @ArKE Well, a rectangle is a 2D figure, whereas for the purposes of calculating the center of mass you need to take elements of *volume*. It is true, that a cone is the product of the *revolution* of a rectangle, but when revolving it, its outer edge covers a larger distance, thus more mass is closer to the base of the cone, which is why the final center of mass ends up closer to the bottom.

Comment: @LLIAMnYP .. I mean for cylinder .. it is $h/2$ and for a rectangle also it is $h/2$. So if we consider turning a rectangle (width of radius of base for cylinder) by one rotation we can get a cylinder.

Comment: @ArKE that's a matter of coincidence, because for a small cylindrical sector the center of mass is also at $h/2$